# Visual Studio 2017 shows "Change signature" as a quick action. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, automated-refactoring

In Visual Studio 2017 I often see one or more useful Quick Actions (the yellow lightbulb). Most of these actions are effective tools to refactor my code.

But I don't understand the action "Change signature..." (see screenshot below). It seems to pop up all the time, especially when I select a function/sub call. When I select this action I can rearrange the parameters in the call, even if I have only **one** parameter in the call (why rearrange one parameter?). I don't find this action useful at all...

I have tried to find an explaination and/or usefulness of this action. Can anyone explain if I'm missing something important? Or is it simply an annoying feature that I have to live with?

[Screenshot: The Change signature action as a quick action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0iao.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I found this when I googled the problem.

In my case, this was just a matter of myself being impatient and Visual Studio showing errors prematurely. This suggestion will be made if your method returns a type by definition, but no return value is set.